# Windows Azure website security level

Tags: security, azure

I wonder what is the security level for azure hosted websites. Is it Medium/High or Full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They run in **Full Trust** ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0b72a8bb-965f-435b-b096-7ed72fb47853/full-trust-web-site)).

However, they use a *Sandbox* mechanism, and as a result some APIs are not available (e.g. Sockets using IPv6), or do not work as expected (for example, the *Socket.Available* property is unavailable, which restricts the use of some libraries such as [NetFTP](https://netftp.codeplex.com/discussions/535879)).

If you are considering using WA Websites for scenarios in which .NET Security *might* be a problem, I suggest you to get in touch with Microsoft support to ensure that the specific features you may need are supported on this environment.